# Problems with lambda in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have a simple function called `return_funcs` here:

```
>>> def return_funcs():
...     functions = []
...     for i in range(4):
...             functions.append(lambda: i)
...     return functions
```

And when I use `return_funcs` this is what I get:

```
>>> for func in return_funcs():
...     func()
...
3
3
3
```

I was expecting something like:

```
1
2
3
```

Why do I get this unexpected output, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is a lazy language, so the i in your lambda will not be evaluated until you print it. At that point the loop is finished and i kept the last value `3`.

To get your wanted output, use `lambda i=i: i`. This will create an i variable local to each lambda and assign the current i value to it.

Comment: [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) has a very specific meaning, and Python doesn't have it, so I wouldn't call Python a *lazy* language.

Comment: A more detailed explanation: When *lambda: i+5* is called, *i* is looked up as a variable outside the lambda, and at call time the value is the final value 3. When *lambda x=i: x+5* is defined, the default value of x is set, so *i* is looked up at the time of the definition.